# echo array ISO-8859-1 values correctly

Tags: php

I'm having troubles while printing the array values, they are originally encoded with ISO-8859-1 and when echoed they appear with "?". That's so annoying!

I have the charset defined to ISO-8859-15

```
$lang = array();

$lang['HOMEPAGE'] = 'âéíó';

echo $lang['HOMEPAGE'];

result: ????
```

Any hints?

It used to work, using the utf8_decode(); but doesn't seem to solve my problem.

EDIT:

I well, i defined the charset for ISO-8859-15, but i was including the file with the "áúóá" characters, before the html header because of cookie interaction, tried to use ob_start to use cookies on the body but the errors remained, defined charset with header() function and worked well, other solution is:

```
echo iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $lang['PARAGRAFO1']);
```

Comment: I don't know PHP, but I do know one doesn't use utf8_decode to decode something you said isn't UTF-8! Perhaps you just need to use the proper decoding function.

Comment: Don't write solutions by editing the question; write solutions by answering it! Yes, even if it's your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two encodings at work here:

1. The encoding of your text, in this case the source code.
2. The encoding of the webpage. Make sure it's set to ISO-8859-1 as well.
   Put this meta tag in the header of your HTML file to enforce an encoding:

   ```
   <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   ```

Comment: I have in the header the charset defined, i make an include of the file language.php on the index.php, the index.php has that on the header.

Comment: If both encodings are the same it should display correctly. Are you sure your file is ISO-8859-1 as well? Is there perhaps sneaky output buffering going on that does character encoding as well?

Comment: It is very weird, i defined both files with that charset, the output isn't correct. With netbeans i changed the charset aswell of all files. I am going nuts

Comment: i am using iconv function but would love to not have to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output as UTF-8, I suggest you to add those on your initial php script

```
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

Of course you can change to other char if needed.